# Xiaomi - java.lang.SecurityException:Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm having crashes with SecurityException on Fabric just for **Xiaomi MI 5** with **Marshmallow**.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
       at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzi$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzl.disconnect(Unknown Source:4000)
       at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd$1.zza(Unknown Source:1000)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpr$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqa.begin(Unknown Source:1000)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqf.zzd(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqd.zzd(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)
       at com.betvictor.bettingapp.helpers.LocationHelper.startFusedLocationUpdates(LocationHelper.java:1216)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqd.zzd(Unknown Source:12000)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqb.zzapm(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqb.begin(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpu.onConnected(Unknown Source:1000)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$1.onConnected$79e5e33f(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzj.zzl(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzarz(Unknown Source:1000)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zze.zzasb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Permissions of the app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

This is the way that I'm managing the permision:

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // The user already gave permission
        startLocationActions();
    } else {
        // We need to ask the user for permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((MainActivity) mContext,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
    }
```

and then

```
 if (!mDoWeHaveLocation) {
        final LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL_MILLIS);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mFusedLocationListener = new com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                if (!mDoWeHaveLocation) {
                    //do stuff
                }
            }
        };
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, mFusedLocationListener);
    }
```

Someone with the same problem? Or have a clue how to replicate?

Comment: add this in manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: The error message just told you how to solve it, did you even read it ?

Comment: ticket updated with more information. @RRTW thank you for your (un)help

Comment: Try to uninstall your APP(on phone), and clean/rebuild your project, and publish to phone again. Also, try another package name...

Comment: @rguerra you're welcome couse of your original info-less post ~

Comment: @RRTW uninstall the app is something that I can't suggest to the customers that I Dont know who are they. I'm getting this info from fabric

Comment: You should post enough info at first, or you're wasting time...  Since your user used Mi5, he could used Xiaomi's daily build ROM(beta, unstable, that's much Xiaomi user will do, I'm no kidding..). Try to get another Mi5 with stable ROM for test, and post this situation to Xiaomi's official forum.

Comment: Brother, have you solved this issue. I also fetching same problem in Xiaomi device.

Answer (score 0):

Just add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in your AndroidManifest file.

Comment: It is already there. If it was a permission missing on Android Manifest , this problem it was affecting more devices

Comment: Try to run on the another device, maybe it will work normal.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using device with android OS 6.0.1, GPS location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission for android 6.0 in menifest.xml.

Since 6.0 some permissions are considered as "dangerous" (FINE_LOCATION is one of them).

To protect the user, they have to be authorized at runtime, so the user know if it's related to his action. You can check complete example on below link: https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-marshmallow-permissions.html